# Div(message box) is not hiding at runtime using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a login form as following.

```
<li class="loginlink">
    <a id="showlogin" href="#">
        <span style="color: #666666">Login</span>
    </a>
    <div class="loginbox" style="display: block;">
        <fieldset>
            <label>User Name : </label>
            <input id="input" type="text" value="" name="input">
        </fieldset>
        <label>
            <span style="display: inline-block; ...;"> Password :</span>
        </label>
        <input id="password_txt" type="password" style="padding:5px;..;" 
               value="" name="password_txt">
        <p>
            <a class="loginlink" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('headerForm'),
                     {'j_idt60':'j_idt60'},'');return false" style="color: #666666;.." 
                     href="#">Forgot Password?
            </a>

            <a class="loginlink" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('headerForm'),
                      {'j_idt63':'j_idt63'},'');return false" style="..." 
                      href="#">Register 
            </a>
        </p>
        <div class="loginbuttons">
            <input id="loginBtn" type="submit" value="Login" name="loginBtn">
            <input id="cancellogin" type="button" value="Cancel">
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

When you click on **showlogin**. I use jQuery to display it. Like

```
$('#showlogin').click(function(){
    var loginBox = $('.loginbox');
    loginBox.show();
    $('.loginbox fieldset input').focus();
    if (!loginBox.is(':hidden')) {
        validateUser();              
    }         
});

$('#cancellogin').click(function(){
    $('.loginbox').hide();        
});

function validateUser() {       
    $("#loginBtn").click(function(event){

        var userName =  $("#input").val();
        var password = $("#password_txt").val();

        if (userName == "") {                
            $.dialog({                
                message: "UserName must be entered",
                imageIcon: false,
                type: "error",
                okButtonID: "ok",
                okButtonValue: "OK"                  
            });
            return false;               
        } 
        return true;             
    }); //end of click              
} //end of validateUser()
```

Now what is happening suppose i click on the button the box is shown like

[image: Image 1]

Now if i click on login button , then message appears

[image: Image 2]

Now if i click on Ok button. Box get disappear.

[image: Image 3]

Till here things are ok. Now suppose i close the login form by clicking on cancel button. And again open the form

[image: Image 4]

Now again click on login button. The message will appear
[image: Image 5]

But now this time if i click on OK button , then the overlay gone but message don't. Why? I get something like this

[image]

Why this time it is not disappearing? What i am doing wrong? Please help?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for the time it must have taken you to put this together :)

Comment: I think the error is somewhere in the `$.dialog.createUI` function. Can you show us the rest of it?

Comment: Sure :) Edited. You can check the code.

Comment: Is the `containerDivID` correctly added to the container? Check it with your browsers developer tools.

Comment: Oh man.. thats huge code and its a big work to run in local to try to help :( .. anyways.. can you check if validateUser() is getting called 2nd time?(which it should not) if yes probably this code you need to see if (!loginBox.is(':hidden')) {
        validateUser();              
    }

Comment: yes i have checked the code. It comes to the method that's why overlay effect get gone, but i am unable to understand why the message div is still there. If it didn't come in the method second time then overlay should also be there. But overlay gone and message div remain. Confusing. Yes it is long but it's very simple :) Just creating divs and buttons and then appending to divs :)

Comment: @Alex Yes it is appending. When i come to the method second time, then i get the ID #confirm at line `$("#" + config.containerDivID).remove();` No error. It then comes to next line `popupStatus = 0;`. But the message is still there. It should be vanish. Why first time things are going Ok. It happens only when i close the login box and then again start clicking o buttons?

Comment: what does your loadPopup and centerPopup functions look like ?

Comment: @Alex KD i am coming up with two Divs with the ID confirm. Old one is there. And the new one is disappearing. Where i am doing something wrong in my code ?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray Edited. Check the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem relates to your `validateUser()` function. You see every time you show the login box you bind a new click handler that contains the code to show the dialog to the login button.

```
function validateUser() {       
    $("#loginBtn").click(function(event){
    ...
    });
}
```

This means the 2nd time the login box is show the dialog is actually shown twice. The 3rd time the dialog is shown 3 times. You probably can't see this because your centering it. If you drop a Javascript `alert()` function after the line `$.dialog.createUI = function (config) {` you'll see the 2nd time the login is shown you get 2 alerts! See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/kYmcE/) for example of this problem.

Unless your code does something else within the *validate user* function I suggest you drop this function and instead bind the click hander when the document is ready. So you end up with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#loginBtn").click(function (event) {

        var userName = $("#input").val();
        var password = $("#password_txt").val();

        if (userName == "") {
            $.dialog({
                message: "UserName must be entered",
                imageIcon: false,
                type: "error",
                okButtonID: "ok",
                okButtonValue: "OK"
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

    $('#showlogin').click(function () {
        var loginBox = $('.loginbox');
        loginBox.show();
        $('.loginbox fieldset input').focus();
        // code to call validate user removed from here!
    });

    $('#cancellogin').click(function () {
        $('.loginbox').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup you are absolutely right :) I just sorted out the problem and just did the same thing as you suggested just before see your post. Anyways your solution is absolutely correct. Thanks for your help buddy ;) and thanks to every one :)